# Error when compiling a grammar with debug activated

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to debug a boost::spirit grammar that I want to use in a Visual Studio project: This is my code snippet:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

// This is pasted and copied from another header file

namespace StateMachine {
namespace Private {

struct LuaParameterData {
  std::wstring name;
  std::wstring type;
  std::wstring unit;
  std::wstring cardinality;
  std::wstring value;
};

} // namespace Private
} // namespace StateMachine

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
  StateMachine::Private::LuaParameterData,
  (std::wstring, name)
  (std::wstring, type)
  (std::wstring, unit)
  (std::wstring, cardinality)
  (std::wstring, value)
)

// From here original file continues
namespace StateMachine {
namespace Private {

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template<typename Iterator>
struct LuaParameterDataParser : qi::grammar<Iterator, LuaParameterData(), qi::ascii::space_type>
{
  LuaParameterDataParser() : LuaParameterDataParser::base_type(start)
  {
    quotedString %= qi::lexeme['"' >> +(qi::ascii::char_ - '"') >> '"'];

    start %=
      qi::lit("\"parameter\"")
      >> ':'
      >> '{'
      >> qi::lit("\"name\""       ) >> ':' >> quotedString >> ','
      >> qi::lit("\"type\""       ) >> ':' >> quotedString >> ','
      >> qi::lit("\"unit\""       ) >> ':' >> quotedString >> ','
      >> qi::lit("\"cardinality\"") >> ':' >> quotedString >> ','
      >> qi::lit("\"value\""      ) >> ':' >> quotedString
      >> '}'
      ;
  }

  qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), qi::ascii::space_type> quotedString;
  qi::rule<Iterator, LuaParameterData(), qi::ascii::space_type> start;
};

} // namespace Private
} // namespace StateMachine

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_RULE(StateMachine::Private::LuaParameterDataParser<std::string::const_iterator>::quotedString);
```

The macro `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` is defined in project properties.

When I compile it I obtain following errors in the last line where I use `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_RULE` :

> error C3484: syntax error: expected '->' before the return type
>
> error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'register_node'

I don't know if I'm doing the right thing. I want to debug my grammar, but I've seen only hints for debugging rules ([here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/doc-addendum/debugging/) and [here](http://cs.brown.edu/%7Ejwicks/boost/libs/spirit/doc/debugging.html)) so I've tried to adapt my code.

What I'm doing wrong and what I must do in order to print debugging information when I use this grammar with `phrase_parse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field is not static.

Also you're not *showing* the `#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` line (perhaps you specify it at the compiler command line).

The typical approach is to use BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES() e.g.

Notes:

- drop the `classic` include
- any particular reason to use `wstring`?

**<kbd>[Compiling On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f20c6f826c29acf5)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
//#include <boost/spirit/include/classic.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

// This is pasted and copied from another header file

namespace StateMachine {
namespace Private {

    struct LuaParameterData {
        std::wstring name;
        std::wstring type;
        std::wstring unit;
        std::wstring cardinality;
        std::wstring value;
    };

} // namespace Private
} // namespace StateMachine

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
  StateMachine::Private::LuaParameterData,
  (std::wstring, name)
  (std::wstring, type)
  (std::wstring, unit)
  (std::wstring, cardinality)
  (std::wstring, value)
)

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

// From here original file continues
namespace StateMachine {
namespace Private {

    template<typename Iterator>
    struct LuaParameterDataParser : qi::grammar<Iterator, LuaParameterData(), qi::ascii::space_type>
    {
        LuaParameterDataParser() : LuaParameterDataParser::base_type(start)
        {
            quotedString = qi::lexeme['"' >> +(qi::ascii::char_ - '"') >> '"'];

            start =
                qi::lit("\"parameter\"")
                >> ':'
                >> '{'
                >> qi::lit("\"name\""       ) >> ':' >> quotedString >> ','
                >> qi::lit("\"type\""       ) >> ':' >> quotedString >> ','
                >> qi::lit("\"unit\""       ) >> ':' >> quotedString >> ','
                >> qi::lit("\"cardinality\"") >> ':' >> quotedString >> ','
                >> qi::lit("\"value\""      ) >> ':' >> quotedString
                >> '}'
                ;

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(quotedString));
        }

        qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), qi::ascii::space_type> quotedString;
        qi::rule<Iterator, LuaParameterData(), qi::ascii::space_type> start;
    };

} // namespace Private
} // namespace StateMachine

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    std::string const input = R"(
        "parameter" : {
            "name"        : "name"       , 
            "type"        : "type"       , 
            "unit"        : "unit"       , 
            "cardinality" : "cardinality", 
            "value"       : "value"       
        }
    )";
    It f = input.begin(), 
       l = input.end();

    StateMachine::Private::LuaParameterDataParser<It> p;
    StateMachine::Private::LuaParameterData data;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, p, qi::ascii::space, data);

    if (ok) {
        std::wcout << L"Parsed: \n";
        std::wcout << L"\tname: " << data.name << L'\n';
        std::wcout << L"\ttype: " << data.type << L'\n';
        std::wcout << L"\tunit: " << data.unit << L'\n';
        std::wcout << L"\tcardinality: " << data.cardinality << L'\n';
        std::wcout << L"\tvalue: " << data.value << L'\n';
    } else {
        std::wcout << L"Parse failure\n";
    }

    if (f!=l)
        std::wcout << L"Remaining unparsed: '" << std::wstring(f,l) << L"'\n";
}
```

Prints

```
<start>
  <try>\n        "parameter"</try>
  <quotedString>
    <try> "name"       , \n   </try>
    <success>       , \n          </success>
    <attributes>[[n, a, m, e]]</attributes>
  </quotedString>
  <quotedString>
    <try> "type"       , \n   </try>
    <success>       , \n          </success>
    <attributes>[[t, y, p, e]]</attributes>
  </quotedString>
  <quotedString>
    <try> "unit"       , \n   </try>
    <success>       , \n          </success>
    <attributes>[[u, n, i, t]]</attributes>
  </quotedString>
  <quotedString>
    <try> "cardinality", \n   </try>
    <success>, \n            "valu</success>
    <attributes>[[c, a, r, d, i, n, a, l, i, t, y]]</attributes>
  </quotedString>
  <quotedString>
    <try> "value"       \n    </try>
    <success>       \n        }\n  </success>
    <attributes>[[v, a, l, u, e]]</attributes>
  </quotedString>
  <success>\n    </success>
  <attributes>[[[110, 97, 109, 101], [116, 121, 112, 101], [117, 110, 105, 116], [99, 97, 114, 100, 105, 110, 97, 108, 105, 116, 121], [118, 97, 108, 117, 101]]]</attributes>
</start>
Parsed: 
    name: name
    type: type
    unit: unit
    cardinality: cardinality
    value: value
```

Comment: I set `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` in project options so it's used by the compiler. I'll try your approach. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It compiles (thanks) but I obtain no output from the failed parsing, I've set the `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` define, so what I can do? maybe my parser is wrong?

Comment: I see nothing that explains that in your code as shown.  Can you post a SSCCE? As it is you don't parse anything really:)

Comment: @Jepessen I just realized you should drop the `classic` header. Apparently it block the debug feature (I didn't know this). Updated

Comment: I'll check it asap. Sorry if I reply always late, but I'm working in two different places..

Comment: I removed the header. Now the parsers fails (obviously), but at least I've the log. Thanks for your help.