# Parsing comma separated grammars when unordered

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

From a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399161/error-when-compiling-a-grammar-with-debug-activated/28405997#28405997) I found a way to parse with boost::spirit a struct of this type:

```
"parameter" : {
  "name"        : "MyName"       , 
  "type"        : "MyType"       , 
  "unit"        : "MyUnit"       , 
  "cardinality" : "MyCardinality", 
  "value"       : "MyValue"       
}
```

It's a simple JSON with key-value pairs. Now I want to parse this struct regardless to variable orders. I.e. I want to parse into the same object also this struct:

```
"parameter" : {
  "type"        : "MyType"       ,
  "value"       : "MyValue"      ,
  "unit"        : "MyUnit"       , 
  "cardinality" : "MyCardinality",
  "name"        : "MyName"
}
```

I know that I can use the `^` operator in order to parse data in any order but I dont't know how to handles commas at ends of lines but last. How can I parse both structures?

This is the @sehe code from previous post. Grammar is defined here.

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

// This is pasted and copied from another header file

namespace StateMachine {
namespace Private {

    struct LuaParameterData {
        std::wstring name;
        std::wstring type;
        std::wstring unit;
        std::wstring cardinality;
        std::wstring value;
    };

} // namespace Private
} // namespace StateMachine

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
  StateMachine::Private::LuaParameterData,
  (std::wstring, name)
  (std::wstring, type)
  (std::wstring, unit)
  (std::wstring, cardinality)
  (std::wstring, value)
)

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

// From here original file continues
namespace StateMachine {
namespace Private {

    template<typename Iterator>
    struct LuaParameterDataParser : qi::grammar<Iterator, LuaParameterData(), qi::ascii::space_type>
    {
        LuaParameterDataParser() : LuaParameterDataParser::base_type(start)
        {
            quotedString = qi::lexeme['"' >> +(qi::ascii::char_ - '"') >> '"'];

            start =
                qi::lit("\"parameter\"")
                >> ':'
                >> '{'
                >> qi::lit("\"name\""       ) >> ':' >> quotedString >> ','
                >> qi::lit("\"type\""       ) >> ':' >> quotedString >> ','
                >> qi::lit("\"unit\""       ) >> ':' >> quotedString >> ','
                >> qi::lit("\"cardinality\"") >> ':' >> quotedString >> ','
                >> qi::lit("\"value\""      ) >> ':' >> quotedString
                >> '}'
                ;

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(quotedString));
        }

        qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), qi::ascii::space_type> quotedString;
        qi::rule<Iterator, LuaParameterData(), qi::ascii::space_type> start;
    };

} // namespace Private
} // namespace StateMachine

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;

    std::string const input = R"(
        "parameter" : {
            "name"        : "name"       , 
            "type"        : "type"       , 
            "unit"        : "unit"       , 
            "cardinality" : "cardinality", 
            "value"       : "value"       
        }
    )";
    It f = input.begin(), 
       l = input.end();

    StateMachine::Private::LuaParameterDataParser<It> p;
    StateMachine::Private::LuaParameterData data;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, p, qi::ascii::space, data);

    if (ok) {
        std::wcout << L"Parsed: \n";
        std::wcout << L"\tname: " << data.name << L'\n';
        std::wcout << L"\ttype: " << data.type << L'\n';
        std::wcout << L"\tunit: " << data.unit << L'\n';
        std::wcout << L"\tcardinality: " << data.cardinality << L'\n';
        std::wcout << L"\tvalue: " << data.value << L'\n';
    } else {
        std::wcout << L"Parse failure\n";
    }

    if (f!=l)
        std::wcout << L"Remaining unparsed: '" << std::wstring(f,l) << L"'\n";
}
```

Comment: I take no responsibility for that code :)

Comment: Only to specify who knows spirit and who not.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to refer to a set of recent answers where I've been over things quite extensively:

- [Parsing heterogeneous data using Boost::Spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151246/parsing-heterogeneous-data-using-boostspirit/28151398?s=13|0.0000#28151398)
- ad-hoc JSON-like parsing [Reading JSON file with C++ and BOOST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746109/reading-json-file-with-c-and-boost/27760376#27760376)
- application of a more general JSON grammar: [Reading JSON file with C++ and BOOST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746109/reading-json-file-with-c-and-boost/27749360#27749360)

Tangentially related:

- [Boost Spirit : something like permutation, but not exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234741/boost-spirit-something-like-permutation-but-not-exactly/28237731?s=9|0.0000#28237731)
- http://boost-spirit.com/home/2011/04/16/the-keyword-parser/: the keyword parser

Comment: I'll check them as usual. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I'm using samples from "JSON file with C++ and BOOST" and it seems to work. Thanks again!